# данные из ресурсов в spinner

Tags: android

есть класс DataConversion который хранит число и строку, строка берется из ресурсов, есть массив DataConversion

```
    dataLenght[0] = new DataConversion(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.angstroms), 1e10);

    dataLenght[1] = new DataConversion(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.nanometer), 1e9 );

    dataLenght[2] = new DataConversion(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.micrometers), 1e6);

    dataLenght[3] = new DataConversion(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.millimeter), 1e3);

....
```

и есть spinner которому и скармливается этот массив, но когда список раскрывается видно полное вместо строки из ресурса видно  ее имя com.exemple ...
когда значение выбрано, отражается нормально

public class DataConversion {

```
public String text;

public double factor;

public DataConversion(String text, double factor) {
    this.factor = factor;
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

из адаптера

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_selected, parent, false);
    }
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_select))
            .setText(getItem(position).text);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: аццкий способ инициализации массива =:)

Comment: спора нет но базу тянуть смысла нет

Comment: покажи больше кода

Comment: добавил, вроде все делаю стандартно, пытался сначала в строку потом в массив не помогло, пробовал передавать int и уже в адаптаре брать строку тот же результат ... когда выбрано все нормально, когда список раскрыт адрес ...

Comment: может вообще не надо было лезть в адаптер?

Comment: сплошная пичалька :(

Answer (score 1):

и то правда)) чет я велосипеды рожаю)) переопределил toString в DataConversion спасибо